# limit of sequence of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that se randomly pick $n$ points in the interval $[0,1]$. We can thinks of the process as $n$ independent uniformly distributed random variables $u_1,\dots,u_n\sim U(0,1)$. Then, we rearrange them:
$$0=v_0<v_1<\cdots <v_n<v_{n+1}=1$$

Now, for every $0\leq k\leq n$, Let $I_k$ be the interval $[v_k,v_{k+1}]$. In every such interval, we decide wheter or not to 'mark' it with probability $|I_k|=v_{k+1}-v_k$. Let $X_n$ be the number of 'marked' intervals in the process.

I am trying to calculate the distribution of $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$, but I am pretty struggling to do so. Hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we decide which intervals are marked in the following way. Once the points $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are established, choose $n+1$ points $x_0,x_1,\dots, x_{n}$, each independent and uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$. Then, we say $I_k$ is marked if and only if $x_k\in I_k$, that is if $v_k<x_k<v_{k+1}$.

From this, it is easy to see that the probability that $I_k$ is marked is $\frac1{n+1}$. To figure out  whether $I_k$ is marked, you need only look at the points $u_1,\dots, u_n$ and $x_k$. Then, $I_k$ is marked if and only if $x_k$ is the $(k+1)^\text{st}$ smallest of these $n+1$ points. Since each rank for $x_k$ is equally likely, the probability of having the correct rank is $\frac1{n+1}$.

Hmmm, there are $n+1$ intervals, each with a probability of $\frac1{n+1}$ of being marked. If the intervals were marked independently of each other, the distribution would be $\text{Bin}(n+1,\frac1{n+1})$, which is Poisson$(1)$ in the limit. To deal with the dependence, we use the method of moments. That is, we are done as long as we can show $\Bbb E\left[\binom{X_n}{k}\right]\to 1/k!$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$, we can conclude $X_n$ converges to Poisson$(1)$ in distribution.

Writing $X_n$ as a sum of $n+1$ indicator variables corresponding to whether $I_k$ is marked, $\binom{X_n}{k}$ is equal to the number of subsets of size $k$ of $\{I_0,\dots,I_n\}$ for which all intervals in that subset are marked. By linearity of expectation, and the symmetry of the problem,
$$
\Bbb E\left[\binom{X_n}{k}\right]
  =\binom{n+1}{k}\cdot \Bbb P(I_0,I_1,\dots,I_{k-1}\text{ are all marked})
$$
Now, what is the probability that $I_0,\dots,I_{k-1}$ are all marked? This occurs if, in the sorted list of the points
$$
u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n,\;x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{k-1}
$$
we have $x_0$ is ranked smallest, $x_1$ is the third smallest, $\dots$, up to $x_{k-1}$ being the $(2k-1)^\text{st}$ smallest. Each of the $(n+k)!$ orderings of the points are equally likely, and there are $n!$ valid orderings (the relative orderings of $u_1,\dots,u_n$ can be anything, after which the placement of $x_0,\dots,x_{k-1}$ is forced). Therefore, the probability is $n!/(n+k)!$, so
$$
\Bbb E\left[\binom{X_n}{k}\right]=\binom{n+1}k\cdot\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \frac1{k!}
$$

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the detailed answer. Though, there is one thing that I don't understand - What do you mean by saying the method of moments, why are you calculating the limit of the expected value?

Comment: I am referring to [this method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(probability_theory)). The result in that wiki article is pretty important for probability research, though I confess I do not know the proof in full generality. $\tag*{}$ You may be worried that the wiki article deals with $E[X_n^k]$, while my answer uses $E[\binom{X_n}k]$. These are equivalent, since$$E[X_n^k]=\sum_{i=1}^k {k \brace i}\cdot i!\cdot \binom{X_n}{i},$$ so convergence of $E[\binom{X_n}{k}]$ implies that of $E[X_n^k]$. Here, ${k\brace i}$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: In my last comment, the left-hand-side of my displayed equation should have $X^k_n$, instead of $E[X^k_n]$. @TairGalili